# git version control directory of root file system

Tags: git

I have downloaded a tar file which is Linux-Sample-Root-Filesystem and extracted to a directory.I want to use git version control on the directory.But somehow file size is abnomal.

The original size of directory is 3.6G then use git to control the directory(git add and commit).However it becomes 3.8G after checkout the HEAD.

I also try git-lfs(Large File Storage) ,it doesn't work.

How should I use git to control such a Linux-Sample-Root-Filesystem directory?
Any piece of information ,I will be so thankful for your help.

```
tar -xf Tegra_Linux_Sample-Root-Filesystem_R32.2.1_aarch64.tbz2  -C rootfs/

root@richard-VMBox:/home/richard/Desktop/example# du -sh rootfs/
3.6G    rootfs/    ####The rootfs directory total size is 3.6G. 

List of each sub-directories size.
root@richard-VMBox:/home/richard/Desktop/example/rootfs# du -sh */
12M     bin/
80K     boot/
4.0K    dev/
12M     etc/
4.0K    home/
353M    lib/
4.0K    media/
4.0K    mnt/
4.0K    opt/
4.0K    proc/
12K     root/
132K    run/
11M     sbin/
4.0K    snap/
4.0K    srv/
4.0K    sys/
4.0K    tmp/
3.1G    usr/
134M    var/
```

- git add rootfs/
- git commit -m "add rootfs/ dir"

```
 root@richard-VMBox:/home/richard/Desktop/example# rm -rf rootfs/
```

`root@richard-VMBox:/home/richard/Desktop/example# git reset --hard HEAD
...Checking out files: 100% (113421/113421), done.
HEAD is now at a65e1fe81 add rootfs dir


root@richard-VMBox:/home/richard/Desktop/example# du -sh rootfs/
3.8G    rootfs/           ###File size is bigger.
root@richard-VMBox:/home/richard/Desktop/example/rootfs# du -sh */
12M     bin/
80K     boot/
4.0K    dev/
12M     etc/
4.0K    home/
335M    lib/
4.0K    media/
4.0K    mnt/
4.0K    opt/
4.0K    proc/
12K     root/
132K    run/
11M     sbin/
4.0K    snap/
4.0K    srv/
4.0K    sys/
4.0K    tmp/
3.3G    usr/
134M    var/`

Comment: Go further and check (compare) */lib* and */usr* contents.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not a good idea to version control entire file systems.  Version control tools like Git tend to work best on text files, and storing large binary files is not recommended.  Git also doesn't support things you may want like hard links, user and group permissions, or any permissions other than 644 and 755.

If you really want to do this, you may want to look into something like `pristine-tar`, which stores files and the difference between those files and the tarball itself.

The reason you're seeing the increase in file size is because of the `.git` directory.  When you check files into Git, all the files and directories have their contents stored compressed inside the `.git` directory.  As a result, the extra 200 MB is probably from that data being stored.

Comment: OK,I will try pristine-tar. It seems like git not suitable for root file system.